# Intent is losing values in extras

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I have a `GCMIntentService` where I am setting details for the intent and all when the user clicks on the notification. My code snippet relevant to this is below:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CustomTabActivity.class);
if (noteId != null && value != null) {
    notificationIntent.putExtra("noteId", noteId);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("value", value);
}

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Notification updateComplete = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(msg)
        .setTicker(title)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .build();

notificationManager.notify(100, updateComplete);
```

Whenever `CustomTabActivity.class` is opened, the `getExtras()` call is always null. Why is it that I am not able to get the values from intent?

I read the following for this and was not able to solve it:

[Pass a String from one Activity to another Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707900/how-to-pass-string-one-activity-to-another)

[Android - how can I send a GCM push notification with instructions of which activity to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349385/android-how-can-i-send-a-gcm-push-notification-with-instructions-of-which-acti)

Comment: Are you sure the `if` condition is ever true?

Comment: Is `CustomTabActivity` already running in background when `notificationIntent` is posted?

Comment: If is always true, when I ran it with break points. `CustomTabActivity` is sometimes in background and sometimes not. But regardless, it still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bulk of the problem here. Turns out that since I had `singleTop` for the activity, the intent from `getIntent()` was the old one. This code works:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        String noteId = intent.getExtras().getString("noteId");
        String value = intent.getExtras().getString("value");
    }
}
```

`onNewIntent` gets called when the user clicks the notification.

Answer (score -1):

**Try This :**

```
private static int count = 1;

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, (int)(Math.random() * 100), new Intent(),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, gcmData.getString("message"), when);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, gcmData.getString("type"), intent.getExtras().getString("message"), contentIntent);
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(count, notification);
            count = count + 1;
```